# Higlight text while playing mp3

Tags: javascript, html, jplayer

I want to know how they did this:
http://al-quran.info/#1:1

When you play a verse, the second verse will play after it. It also highlights the text that is "playing". Is there an example I can work with or anything?

So what I want is to click on play at verse A and it automatically plays, highlights and scrolls B,C etc. after that.

How do I do this? I know this is done with Jplayer but I don't know much.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It looks like they used some css/html to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the HTML5 audio players are using [HTML5 audio elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video). From the javascript point of view you can access bunch of useful methods and properties defined in [HTMLMediaElement Interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement)

just to give you a picture here is some example code with naive algorithm:

```
var audioElement;
audioElement = document.getElementById('audioElementID');
while(isPlaying()){
    if(audioElement.ended){ //Indicates whether the media element has ended playback.
        playAndHighlightNext();
    }
}
```